# Selecting from an array based on size

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm currently working on a small game and got stuck on something I can't figure out.

I have an array with 5 items in, these items represent different positions, like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

These are basically different lines that are used to place objects as the players goes further into the game.

Every 5 second new objects should appear, these come from another array, that looks something like this:

```
[1, 2]
 // 1 = single item
 // 2 = double item
```

1 and 2 are different types of objects, both require a different amount of lines.

The problem is that these items sometimes overlap and I can't figure out how to stop this.

You can see the problem from the output:

```
Items: [1, 2]
[Item of type 1] line: 3 
[available lines] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[Item of type 2] line: 2
[available lines] [1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 5]
```

So item 1 (1 line) is placed on line 3, but for item 2 (2 lines), line 2 is select, because it's 2 lines wide, this will overlap with my first item.

So basically for item 2 only line 1 and 4 could be selected, but I can't seem to find any logic that would only select these.

It's probably going to be expanded into something around 20 lines with more objects, so I would need to find a way to select a line where the next one is available too.

Any ideas on how I can get started on this?

What I currently use is this:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (start_lines.length - 1));
var line = start_lines[random];

// If it's a barrier, delete 2 rows instead (35)
if(type == 2) {
    if(line == 5) {
        xPos = this._lines[random - 1] - 35;
        start_lines.splice(random - 1, 2);
    } else {
        xPos = this._lines[random] - 35;
        start_lines.splice(random, 2);
    }
} else {
    start_lines.splice(random, 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you create like, an mspaint visualizing your question? Im having a hard time following the problem. Perhaps the whole code in question would help as well.

Comment: You have to make the random selection based on `type`. If `type` is 2 you have to select only a line for which the next line is available.

Comment: @tracevipin, I know, and that's exactly where I'm struggling

Comment: @JakeHeidt I hope this helps to clarify it: http://i.imgur.com/xHusxXm.png, the cone was selected for line 2, after that the barrier was selected for line 1, but there's not enough space to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for now was first loop trough the array with lines and check if the next line is available, I then push those 2 lines into another array which I can select from.

```
if(type == 2) {
    var options = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < start_lines.length; i++) {
        var f = start_lines[i];
        var n = start_lines[i + 1];

        if((f + 1) == n) {
            options.push([f, n]);
        }
    }

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.length - 1));
    var option = options[random];

    var f = option[0];
    var n = option[1];

    xPos = this._lines[f] - 30;

    start_lines.splice(f - 1, 2);
    start_lines.splice(n - 1, 2);
} else {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (start_lines.length - 1));
    var line = start_lines[random];

    start_lines.splice(random, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this approach fits for your requirement, but it would be better if you can set the lines initially and randomly pick one when needed. This avoids a lot of confusion.

```
function getLines(){
  var start_lines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lines = [];
  while(start_lines.length){
    var type = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2);
    lines.push(start_lines.splice(0, type));
  }
  return lines;
}
var lines = getLines();

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
console.log(lines.splice(random, 1));
```

Here I am selecting `type` randomly - either 1 or 2. You will have to make some changes in this.

jsbin : http://jsbin.com/upabom/3/edit

Comment: This won't work for me, there's no detection wether the next two lines are available or not.
Let's say the first line is `3`, `2` can still be selected for `type 2`

Comment: I think that can be achieved with this. Did you check the console output in jsbin ?